# How to filter specific records using a combobox and display in a subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to filter records from a combobox, if I select Cape Town only Cape Town records must show in the subform but if I select Durban only Durban records must display in the subform. I dont get any errors but if I Select Cape Town only Cape Town records shows and as soon as I select Durban the the Cape Town records still display it doesn change to show the Durban records in the subform. Heres my code below any help will be much appreciated Thanks

```
 If Me.Combo0.Value Then
   strFilters = "Sites = 'Cape Town'"

   DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
Forms!Home![Plant Transaction subform].Form.Filter = strFilters
Forms!Home![Plant Transaction subform].Form.FilterOn = True

   ElseIf Me.Combo0.Value Then
   strFilters = "Sites = 'Durban'"

      DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
Forms!Home![Plant Transaction subform].Form.Filter = strFilters
Forms!Home![Plant Transaction subform].Form.FilterOn = True

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your tables are set up right you should be able to do this with little / no coding at all.

Lets create a table called destinations and put 3 fields in: Unique ID, Townname and Area: example:

> ## ID     |   TownName    | Areas
>
> CT      |   CapeTown    | PlaceWithinCapetown 
>   CT      |   CapeTown    | AnotherPlace 
>   D       |   Durban      | PlaceHereAswell

so on and so on.

Lets assume you have 2 elements on your form. A Combobox and a Listbox.

**ComboBox -** List of Towns 
**ListBox -** List of Areas Within Town.

Lets say the combobox is called cboTowns and the ListBox is called lstAreas

Click on the combobox and in the Row Source place your query, Something like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT destinations.ID, destinations.TownName FROM destinations;
```

Here i have asked for the Unique ID and Town name and set my bound column to 2 (So Only The Town Name Shows when user selected one), Now your combobox is populated with the towns, You will note the towns are listed more than once. You need to change the property's of your query to allow Unique values only Go to Row Source, Click on 3 dots this take's you to query builder select a blank area and on the right find the setting Unique Values set this to Yes and the combobox is complete.

Now i have the list of Towns and the Unique ID we can get the listbox to start working. Before you move on if you List all of your information all in 1 table as detailed above it is easier to lookup the data. If its over 2 tables you will need to create a relationship in Access. before moving on.

Once done go to the list box and again in your row source you want to put something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT destinations.ID, destinations.Areas FROM destinations WHERE (((destinations.ID)=[Forms]![FormName]![cboTowns])) ORDER BY destinations.Areas;
```

So here i told it to look for Unique ID that's been set via combobox and then look for areas attached to that Unique ID.

Every time the user selects a an entry from the drop-down box the list box updates straight away. no other coding needed. If you have more information and need to display other things you can then use the DLookup function to populate any other fields you might have.

I will also say if you don't want to restructure what you already have looking at the code you supplied I noticed you are not requerying anything. You will need a Me.requery after end if in order to refresh the form. otherwise it will not update anything.